# React-Redux Menu?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've created a menu component that I'd like to have redux manage the state of.

I have a `MenuStore` looks something like this:

```
export interface MenuState {
    isOpen: boolean;
}    

interface ToggleMenuAction {
    type: 'TOGGLE_MENU';
    isOpen: boolean;
}

export const actionCreators = {
    toggleMenu: (): AppThunkAction<ToggleMenuAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
         dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_MENU', isOpen: !getState().menu.isOpen});
    },
};

export const reducer: Reducer<MenuState> = (state: MenuState, action: ToggleMenuAction) => {
    if (action.type === 'TOGGLE_MENU') {
        return {
            isOpen: action.isOpen
        };
    }
    return state || { isOpen: false };
};
```

And an `Implementation` like this:

```
export class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}> {
    public render(): any {
        return <div>
            <Menu  />
            { this.props.children }
            </div>;
    }
}
```

Which yields this error:

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>
>   & Read...'.
>         Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
>           Property 'isOpen' is missing in type '{}'.

**Question:**

1. I realize that the component needs to be provided these state props... but to be honest... I don't know how.

Disclaimer. I'm still extremely novice with React & Redux... (Decided to jump into the thick of things) But when I use this same "pattern" for component loaded via the router, it works... so I'm guessing there is some magic happening in the background, where their props get loaded some other way. But as I'm manually creating the element `<Menu />` that ability is lost..

(Also, I'm mirroring the [dotnetcore](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) react-redux's sample projects code (in terms of store layout etc, but this is my attempt at breaking out of the mold a bit and seeing how to do this)

---

**Update** (as this might be relevant)

My Menu component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// other imports like "reactstrap", etc;

import * as MenuStore from '../store/Menu';
import {ApplicationState}  from '../store';

// At runtime, Redux will merge together...
type MenuProps =
    MenuStore.MenuState      
    & typeof MenuStore.actionCreators ;    
export class Menu extends React.Component<MenuProps, {}> {      

    public render(): any {

        return <Navbar toggleable>
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
                My App
            </NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarToggler onClick={ () => { this.props.toggleMenu(); } } />
            <Collapse isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                <Nav navbar>
                    <NavLink>Something</NavLink>
                </Nav>
            </Collapse>
        </Navbar>;
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.menu, 
    MenuStore.actionCreators 
)(Menu);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being extracting the menu out of the app component and, having it rather be a higher / super root in my router

```
export const routes = <App>
    <Route component={ Menu } />
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home }/>
    <Route path='/search/:keywords?' component={ SearchResults }/>
    <Route path='/listing/:listingId' component={ Listing }/>
</App>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely should not use Redux for this purpose.  Redux is meant to manage state that is relevant in a wider context for the entirety of your app.  Information that is relevant to one and only one component should be managed by that component itself.

That said, so that you can properly use Redux when you find a good need for it, the piece of the puzzle you seem to be missing is the `connect` funtcion: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: Yes, while I do realize this is an odd situation. But for my use case, 40% of my users use Opera Mini in data saving mode, which, this, coupled with SSR... would enable me to have the menu work on older devices (sort of a graceful degradation of sorts)... I do realize the strangeness of this... but I'd like to explore how this would work. (as this approach pretty much solve(d) a few of my other requirements) :) But thank you... let me revisit my code and see if your suggestion / answer solves my question. (I'll accept then)

Comment: Ive appended my menu component, and I do utilize connect on there... but (and I'm guessing) you might be suggesting I add a connect to my app root? How would I go about this?

Comment: It seems your situation has a number of unique variables that weren't clear at first.  Your error message seems to be a typescript error, and is more specific to TS than it is to react.  I would resubmit the question in that context, while also mentioning that you need a solution that works on opera mini.

Comment: Will do. To be clear/fair though, erm... opera mini is (although in scope of this question) not too relevant, as in solving the issue, as I posted at first... would solve my business requirement too :) with regards to TS, I have faked the required properties in my tinkering, and while it does get TS to pass, it doesn't solve the problem that the menu state isn't bound to the component, thus the TS error in the regard (I'm assuming) is just safe guarding agains the actual issue, which is the scope/props/whatever not being provided to the component